# What is the difference between []string and ...string in golang?

Tags: string, go

In the Go language,

`[]string` is a string array

and we also use `...string` as a parameter.

What is the difference?

Function definition:

```
func f(args ...string) {}
```

Can I call this function like below?

```
args := []string{"a", "b"}

f(args)
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

> `[]string` is a string array

Technically it's a slice that references an underlying array

> and we also use `...string` as a parameter.
>
> What is the difference?

With respect to the structure, nothing really. The data type resulting from both syntax is the same.

The `...` parameter syntax makes a variadic parameter. It will accept zero or more `string` arguments, and reference them as a slice.

With respect to calling `f`, you can pass a slice of strings into the variadic parameter with the following syntax:

```
func f(args ...string) {
    fmt.Println(len(args))
}


args := []string{"a", "b"}

f(args...)
```

This syntax is available for either the slice built using the literal syntax, or the slice representing the variadic parameter *(since there's really no difference between them)*.

http://play.golang.org/p/QWmzgIWpF8

Comment: `[]string` is a slice, not an array. The differences between an array and slice are subtle but important.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg: Yes, my "nothing really" answer to the "what's the difference" quote is answering the question that was asked about the difference between the slice generated by the variadic function parameter, and the one created using the `[]string` syntax. I'll add more of the quote to my answer to make it clearer. :-)

Comment: @IHateLazy Is there a way to make builtin `println` work with ellipsis? [Here](http://play.golang.org/p/lJKJbhC1a1) you can find my experiments. If someone wishes some debug print functions, go watch my playgound.

Answer (score 16):

Both create an array of strings, but the difference is in how it is called.

```
func f(args ...string) {

}
// Would be called like this:

f("foo","bar","baz");
```

This allows you to accept a variable number of arguments (all of the same type)

A great example of this is `fmt.Print` and friends, which can accept as few or as many arugments as you want.

Comment: I'm no Go expert, but isn't one variadic arguments and the other a single array argument, and aren't the two distinct like in other languages?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yup. If that's not clear then sorry for the confusion. The first line about both creating an array just means that the resultant argument in both instances is an array. It's nearly identical to python's `def fn(*args)` construction.

Comment: So Go exposes variadic arguments as an instance of an array type? That's pleasing.

Comment: Actually they both create a slice of strings, Not an array. They are different things in golang.

Comment: Both don't create an "array" of strings, they create a "slice" of strings.

Comment: Helpful for me ... +1

Answer (score 6):

Here is what you want:

```
var args []string = []string{"A", "B", "C"}

func Sample(args ...string) {
    for _, arg := range args {
        fmt.Println(arg)
    }
}

func main() {
    Sample(args...)
}
```

Play: http://play.golang.org/p/N1ciDUKfG1

Answer (score 2):

It simplifies your function parameters. Here is an example(https://play.golang.org/p/euMuy6IvaM):
Method SampleEllipsis accepts from zero to many parameters of the same type but in the method SampleArray it is mandatory **args** to be declared.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func SampleEllipsis(args ...string) {
    fmt.Printf("Sample ellipsis : %+v\n",args)
}


func SampleArray(args []string) {
    fmt.Println("Sample array ")
    SampleEllipsis(args...)
}

func main() {
    // Method one
    SampleEllipsis([]string{"A", "B", "C"}...)
    // Method two
    SampleEllipsis("A", "B", "C")
    // Method three
    SampleEllipsis()

    // Simple array
    SampleArray([]string{"A", "B", "C"})

    // Simple array
    SampleArray([]string{})

}
```

Returns :

```
Sample ellipsis : [A B C]
Sample ellipsis : [A B C]
Sample ellipsis : []
Sample array 
Sample ellipsis : [A B C]
Sample array 
Sample ellipsis : []
```